# CodeForces 750D- New Year and Fireworks Time Limit Exceeded

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, memoization, brute-force

I am unable to optimise the [following dynamic programming problem:](http://codeforces.com/contest/750/problem/D)
This is my JAVA solution for the problem with the [following test cases](http://codeforces.com/contest/750/submission/23472702).The limit gets exceeded on higher recursion levels. I am unable to understand how memoization can be implemented in this case. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;


public class ProblemD {
    static class Fireworks{
        boolean occupied;
        int dir;
        public Fireworks(boolean occupied,int dir){
            this.occupied=occupied;
            this.dir=dir;
        }
    }
    public static void fireworks(Fireworks f[][],int i,int j,int levels[],int n){
        if(n<levels.length){

            for(int k=1;k<levels[n];k++){

                if(f[i][j].dir==0){
                    f[i+1][j]=new Fireworks(true,0);
                    i=i+1;
                }
                else if(f[i][j].dir==45){
                    f[i+1][j-1]=new Fireworks(true,45);
                    i=i+1;
                    j=j-1;
                }
                else if(f[i][j].dir==90){
                    f[i][j-1]=new Fireworks(true,90);
                    j=j-1;
                }
                else if(f[i][j].dir==135){
                    f[i-1][j-1]=new Fireworks(true,135);
                    i=i-1;
                    j=j-1;
                }
                else if(f[i][j].dir==180){
                    f[i-1][j]=new Fireworks(true,180);
                    i=i-1;
                }
                else if(f[i][j].dir==225){
                    f[i-1][j+1]=new Fireworks(true,225);
                    i=i-1;
                    j=j+1;
                }
                else if(f[i][j].dir==270){
                    f[i][j+1]=new Fireworks(true,270);
                    j=j+1;
                }
                else{
                    f[i+1][j+1]=new Fireworks(true,315);
                    i=i+1;
                    j=j+1;
                }

            }
            //n++;

        if(f[i][j].occupied && n<levels.length-1){

            if(f[i][j].dir==0){
                    f[i+1][j-1]=new Fireworks(true,45);
                    f[i+1][j+1]=new Fireworks(true,315);
                     fireworks(f,i+1,j-1,levels,n+1);
                     fireworks(f,i+1,j+1,levels,n+1);
                     return;
                }
            else if (f[i][j].dir==45){
                    f[i][j-1]=new Fireworks(true,90);
                    f[i+1][j]=new Fireworks(true,0);
                    fireworks(f,i,j-1,levels,n+1);
                    fireworks(f,i+1,j,levels,n+1);
                    return;
            }
            else if(f[i][j].dir==90){
                    f[i+1][j-1]=new Fireworks(true,45);
                    f[i-1][j-1]=new Fireworks(true,135);
                    fireworks(f,i+1,j-1,levels,n+1);
                    fireworks(f,i-1,j-1,levels,n+1);
                    return;

            }
            else if(f[i][j].dir==135){
                    f[i][j-1]=new Fireworks(true,90);
                    f[i-1][j]=new Fireworks(true,180);

                    fireworks(f,i,j-1,levels,n+1);
                    fireworks(f,i-1,j,levels,n+1);
                    return;
            }
            else if(f[i][j].dir==180){
                    f[i-1][j-1]=new Fireworks(true,135);
                    f[i-1][j+1]=new Fireworks(true,225);

                    fireworks(f,i-1,j-1,levels,n+1);
                    fireworks(f,i-1,j+1,levels,n+1);
                    return;
            }
            else if(f[i][j].dir==225){

                    f[i-1][j]=new Fireworks(true,180);
                    f[i][j+1]=new Fireworks(true,270);  

                    fireworks(f,i-1,j,levels,n+1);
                    fireworks(f,i,j+1,levels,n+1);
                    return;

            }
            else if(f[i][j].dir==270){

                    f[i-1][j+1]=new Fireworks(true,225);
                    f[i+1][j+1]=new Fireworks(true,315);

                    fireworks(f,i-1,j+1,levels,n+1);
                    fireworks(f,i+1,j+1,levels,n+1);
                    return;

            }
            else {
                    f[i+1][j]=new Fireworks(true,0);
                    f[i][j+1]=new Fireworks(true,270);

                    fireworks(f,i+1,j,levels,n+1);
                    fireworks(f,i,j+1,levels,n+1);
                    return;
            }
            }
        }
        else{
            return;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Fireworks f[][];
            f=new Fireworks[500][500];
            for(int i=0;i<500;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<500;j++){
                    f[i][j]=new Fireworks(false,0);

                }
            }
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            int start=250;
            int n=sc.nextInt();
            int levels[]=new int[n];
            f[start][start].occupied=true;
            f[start][start].dir=0;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                levels[i]=sc.nextInt();
            }
            fireworks(f,start,start,levels,0);
            int count=0;
            for(int i=0;i<500;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<500;j++){
                    if(f[i][j].occupied){
                        System.out.println(i+" "+j);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```